# Android: Trying to use a inbuilt layout xml file - simple_list_item_2_single_choice symbol cannot be resolved

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I'm trying to create a listview where each item in the listview has two lines of text and a radio button at the end, so you can select one of the items in the list and then click next.

simple_list_item_2_single_choice.xml does exactly this, and it is integrated into android.

I have already used simple_list_item_2 which is built in for android on another screen without problems, and I can see that simple_list_item_2_single_choice is in 
...\android-studio\sdk\platforms\android-20\data\res\layout

but when I try to reference it in my code, I get the error: cannot resolve symbol 'simple_list_item_2_single_choice'

Does anyone know how to make my app recognize this inbuilt file?

Comment: What path are you using to set that xml file? it should be android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2_single_choice

Comment: What is your minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion?

Comment: im using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2_single_choice to reference it, previously I used android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2 in another screen and it worked.
minSdkVersion 11
targetSdkVersion 19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to make my app recognize this inbuilt file?

Step #1: Copy the file into your app project.

Step #2: Reference your copy from your Java code.

While that layout file may be part of Android, it is not part of the Android SDK, as you will not see that resource listed in [the `android.R.layout` package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html).

Comment: Thanks for response, yes I already came up with that, but that caused me to get more cannot be resolved errors, as the xml file uses some resources that are apparently not in this android.R.layout packacke either, I guess I just have to add them into my app too.

Comment: It worked for me. Just remember to reference the XML layout as `R.layout.simple_list_item_2_single_choice` (dropping the `android` prefix before `R`) and making sure you import your own project’s `R`—this is because you are now referring to a resource within your app, not an Android resource. Do note, however, that the XML layout itself still has some IDs declared as `@android:id/text1` and similar—these need to be referenced as e.g. `android.R.id.text1`.